# Indexing using a boolean matrix in R

Tags: r, indexing, boolean, radix

I'm stumped using indexing in R. I have two matrices, one with logical values and one with data. I want to use the first to index into the second one. However, I've noticed that R reorders my values when doing so.

My data looks roughly like this:

```
ind <- matrix(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), nrow = 3, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

data <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), nrow = 3, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

Now, when indexing `result <- data[ind]`, I was obtaining the following: `c(1, 3, 4)` when I was trying to obtain `c(1, 4, 3)`.

How can I prevent R from reordering columwise? I'd appreciate any input. I'm sure it's an easy fix - I just don't know which.

Thank you!

Comment: Matrices are column-major in R. You can always transpose: `t(data)[t(ind)]`

Answer (score 1):

When converting matrices to and from vectors, R makes the transformation columnwise.

```
as.vector(data) 
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

As this happens to both your `ind` and your `data` this is generally not a problem.

So to retain *your* order, you have to transpose both matrices:

```
> t(data)[t(ind)]
[1] 1 4 3
```

PS: have you tried `which` with a matrix?

```
> which(arr.ind = T, ind)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   3   3
[3,]   2   4
```

Comment: Thank you - this just saved me a lot of time! Also, I now begin to understand what column-major means. Much apppreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R trick (but I recommend the answer by [@c0bra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69072061/12158757))

```
> rowSums(data * ind)
[1] 1 4 3
```